# Determine if phototransistor is in cutoff

Tags: stm32, phototransistor

I'm attempting to determine if the following phototransistor [HOA1870-031](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Honeywell%20Sensing%20&%20Control%20PDFs/HOA1870-031.pdf) is in cutoff.

The [HOA1870-031](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Honeywell%20Sensing%20&%20Control%20PDFs/HOA1870-031.pdf) we have in stock have the cathode of the IR emitter tied to the emitter of the IR detector (phototransistor).

What I want to do is detect whether the phototransistor is in cutoff (the light between the IR emitter and IR detector is blocked).

To do this I'm reading the voltage with an analog input (`PA1`) which is connected internally to a comparator (`COMP1`) in the [STM32F303VC](http://st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00043574-stm32f303xb-c-d-e-stm32f303x6-8-stm32f328x8-stm32f358xc-stm32f398xe-advanced-arm-based-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf#page=589&zoom=100,89,464).

When the phototransistor is saturated I read a voltage of `≈230mV` after the voltage drop across the `10KΩ` resister.

When the phototransistor is in cutoff I read a voltage of `≈2.9V` (`VCE ≈ VCC ≈ 3V`).

I set the inverting input of `COMP1` to `VREFINT` and the non-inverting input to `PA1`.
I'm also reducing some noise via the configurable `hysteresis` for the comparator.

I've tested it and things seem to be working as expected, when the light is blocked between the IR emitter and the IR detector the `ISR` I configured is fired.

Although I did go to school for EE I've been writing software for so many years that I've forgotten most of what I had learned (which really sucks).

I dug out all of my old text books which helped me come up with the circuit you see below.

My question here is, am I doing anything obviously wrong?

Is there a better way to accomplish this (detecting if the light is broken between the IR emitter and IR detector)?

[image: Currently implemented circuit]

Comment: For a cleaner cutoff recess the devices in a 5mm aperture. But for high volume PD’s are far more accurate without hFE tolerances

Comment: Looks good. You might check that high levels of ambient light can not pull the analog voltage too near the lower hysteresis threshold, when the aperture is blocked. Not likely, but sunlight might do it. You can reduce sensitivity by decreasing value of collector resistor.

Comment: The thing to keep in mind is that the transistor is trying to draw a fixed (approximately) amount of current. With a 10k resistor, the voltage across the resistor is negligeable, so the voltage across the transistor is very near Vc. BUT. If you use the isolator in a circuit with a larger resistor, the resistor voltage will be larger (Ohm's Law, right?) and the transistor voltage will be less - and in the worst case the transistor leakage could cause what looks like saturation. So keep in mind that your test is only valid for the resistor value (10k) which you have used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That all looks fine.

- You have current limiting on your LED. If it's an infrared LED it will have a forward voltage drop of about 1.4 V which leaves 1.6 V across its resistor. The current will be V/R = 1.6/100 = 16 mA which should be fine.
- Your 10k resistor on the transistor will limit the maximum on current to 3/10k = 0.3 mA which is also fine.

I would have suggested using hysteresis but you've addressed that already.